# Compiler error on array declaration?

Tags: c++

How do I go about fixing these three errors?

- error C2057: expected constant expression
- error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
- error C2133: 'randomTickets' : unknown size

Line that's having the issue and not liking [tickets]

```
int randomTickets[tickets][SIZE];
```

---

```
//global constants
const int SIZE = 6;                     //This is the number of balls per ticket
const int MAX_WHITE = 58;               //This is the range of the white balls
const int MAX_RED = 34;                 //This is the range of the red balls
const int waysToWin = 9;
int* newAr = new int[SIZE];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int tickets = displayMenu();        //Welcome screen lets you buy tickets
    int spending = tickets * 2;         //Charges you for the tickets
    int randomTickets[tickets][SIZE];
//code
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Make `tickets` a constant expression and make sure it's value is greater than zero.

Comment: Can you explain what part of the error message you don't understand? "Expected constant expression" is pretty straightforward. Is it that you don't know where it was expected? (You seem to know that, since you isolated it to `tickets`.) Is it that you don't know what a constant expression is?

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<int,SIZE>> randomTickets(tickets);` (and +1 for Raymond's comment).

Answer (score 2):

> error C2057: expected constant expression

You can't declare `randomTickets` like that because the dimensions of the array need to be known at compile time. `tickets` is not a compile time constant and therefore you have the error. Consider using [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> randomTickets(tickets, std::vector<int>(SIZE));
```

Alternatively, you can nest a `std::array` since `SIZE` is constant and known at compile time:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, SIZE>> randomTickets(tickets);
```

The other errors are resolved by fixing this one.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `tickets` is not a constant expression, that's why.

Change `int randomTickets[tickets][SIZE]` as follows:

```
Array* randomTickets = new Array[tickets];
```

Outside of function `main`, declare the following type:

```
typedef int Array[SIZE];
```

You can use variable `randomTickets` as a "normal" 2-dimensional array from this point onwards, just don't forget to `delete[] randomTickets` when you're done...